# Познакомиться с профессией хореограф/хореографа?

Tags: падежи, склонение

Подскажите, на что ориентироваться в таких случаях. Какое правило здесь действует?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно составить грамматически корректное согласованное сочетание профессия хореографа, в случае падежного рассогласования и возникают кавычки, которые выступают именно как графический знак рассогласования: профессия "хореограф".

Comment: Спасибо...

Answer (score 2):

В обычной речи естественнее склонять название профессии, особенно, если название короткое и ясное. "Прочитав воспоминания знаменитого балетмейстера, я познакомился с интереснейшей профессией хореографа." "В профессии хореографа от человека требуются особые качества." И это предпочтительно даже несмотря на грамматическую двусмысленность (у хореографа якобы есть какая-то профессия). Вариант без склонения имеет формальный оттенок и уместен лишь по некоторым поводам. Например, если речь идёт о свойствах экзотической профессии с длинным наименованием, какой-нибудь "оператор машинного доения буйволиной фермы", то несклоняемый вариант оправдан стремлением сформулировать новое для собеседника понятие. В формальных же случаях под профессией чаще подразумевают специальность из официального перечня (этот ВУЗ готовит, в частности, к профессии "оператор ЭВМ"), название которой там обычно пишется без кавычек, но с заглавной буквы, и в такой форме встречается без склонения при формальных ссылках на эти перечни ("мы подготовили столько-то человек по профессии Наладчик станков с программным управлением"). Строго требования вместо такой формы применять кавычки, по-видимому, нет.